# GA4 Config Tag is not firing, but triggers have fired

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

GA4 tag isn't firing on one of many hostnames, despite all triggers firing and no blocking triggers being set. This only happens on this single hostname.

I could likely resolve it by arbitrarily digging into the code and reimplementing GTM, but I'm more interested in dissecting the issue of a tag not firing despite triggers being met. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

[image: GA4 Config Tag Shows Not Fired Though Triggers Have Fired.]

Comment: Do you have any third party tags or scripts on the site which block tracking scripts until cookie consent is given?

Comment: I do not. Also, I've tried to get this tag to fire on various triggers across page load and no luck. UA works fine on this page as well.